# "CoreUI: didn't find parent rendition for" debug message

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

After updating to Xcode 7.2 I started getting the "CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom" debug message. Upon googling this message I found my way to another post on SO: [CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom](http://cuicatalog:%20invalid%20request:%20requesting%20subtype%20without%20specifying%20idiom) which led me to believe that `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "my_image")` somehow was causing the messages.

I worked around the issue by altering these lines of code to `SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTextureAtlas(named: "MySprites").textureNamed("my_image"))`. To make this work I created a folder called MySprites in my Images.xcassets, checked its "Provides Namespace" checkbox and moved all assets into it.

At first, this seemed to be working, but then I started getting the debug message "CoreUI: didn't find parent rendition for 'MySprites/my_image' skipping it" instead. The weird thing is, everything seems to be working as it's supposed to. Only, my debugger log window gets completely spammed with this mysterious message which off course makes debugging hard.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Why am I getting this message? Is there a Sprite Kit guru out there who can point me in the right direction?

If there is something I can do to clarify the issue, please let me know. I find it hard to believe that I am the only one experiencing this.

Comment: try `SKTextureAtlas(named: "Images.xcassets/MySprites").textureNamed("my_image"))`

Comment: Didn't work. This gave me the message "Texture Atlas 'Images.xcassets/MySprites' cannot be found."

Comment: Getting the same debug message